# How to force a remote merge from a pull request on git?

Tags: git, github, merge, bitbucket, git-merge

So I got the main repo (let's call it repo 1) and a fork of it (called repo 2).

When all changes were committed to repo 2 I started a pull request from 2 to 1, then tried to merge on bitbucket website so to downloaded the modified files to the server where repo 1 original files are, and that's when it gives an error:

> Bitbucket cannot automatically merge this request due to conflicts.
>   Review the conflicts on the Overview tab. You can then either decline
>   the request or merge it manually on your local system using the
>   following commands:

```
git checkout master
git remote add danceclub/repo-name ssh://git@bitbucket.org/danceclub/repo-name.git
git fetch danceclub/repo-name
git merge --no-ff -m 'Merged in danceclub/repo-name (pull request #1)' remotes/danceclub/repo-name/master
```

I followed everything and when running the last sentence it gives a conflict warning about merging conflict. being the last sentence:

```
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

How can I fix this?

With a forced merge?

Thank you

Comment: The error output clearly states what you need to do to resolve the problem: `fix conflicts and then commit the result.`  Have you tried doing this?  By the way, the typical way to make a pull request go through is to merge the destination branch into the feature branch which is slated to be merged into the former.

Comment: Excuse my ignorance here but:
Are those conflicts between what there is on repo 1 and repo 2?
Shouldn't a pull request have more weight and update files on repo 1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I fix this?

Run `git status` to see which files have conflicts. Open these files and find every `<<< === >>>` part. Remove the lines you don't want and keep what you want. Save and exit. Then, run `git add` and `git commit` to finish the merge. At last, run `git push` to update the remote repo.

> With a forced merge?

Git has some `strategies` for solving conflicts. Add options `--strategy=recursive -X ours/theirs` to `git merge`, with `ours` to keep current branch's content and `theirs` to adopt the other branch's content instead. But the real case may not be such simple. It's better to edit the conflicting files and decide which lines to keep, and which lines to remove.

Comment: I want to do that but there are at least a hundred files... Can I force to replace files on repo 1 with what there is on repo 2?

Comment: @Carl It's a bit strange there are so many conflicting files. Have all the conflicting files in repo 1 been changed and committed since repo 2 was forked? Is it possible all the files in one repo are of unix style and all in the other are of dos style?

Comment: From the start:
Repo 1 was properly synced (server <> online bitbucket account) and we forked it. 
Worked in several features (developer machine was an ubuntu), committed everything to that fork (repo 2). In these features we modified plenty of files (deleted, also added new ones).

Is this the wrong way of using forks?

Comment: @Carl Make a backup of repo 1. Option One: add `--strategy=recursive -X theirs` to `git merge`. Option Two: make a clone of repo 2, copy its files and overwrite those in repo 1.  But it seems your workflow could be improved because repo 1 and repo 2 are too diverged.

Comment: Going for option 2. Still need to understand why such hassle when trying to merge since a fork is exactly for  that "Work on a feature and then merge with main repo"
Thank you

Comment: @Carl Please check the commit history of the branch in repo 1, and the history in repo 2. There should not have been such big divergence. Possiblity One, two developers are writing one feature separately, one on repo 1's branch and the other on repo 2's branch. Possibility Two, contents of the files are slightly different but file types are different, one of dos style and the other of unix style, which might be a crlf issue produced by working on different systems.